# Get balance from HSBC UK?

Tags: c#, api, onlinebanking

I'm looking for my own personal use to see if I can get the current balance of my HSBC account. I know this is probably not possible but thought I would ask if anyone knows of anything? A quick google didn't turn up any decent results.

Comment: i am not aware about any bank in world has api to pull account details.

Comment: I can't imagine that any bank would ever allow any kind of public API. That'd be a security nightmare waiting to happen!

Comment: Which country? Different countries have different bank law and therefore different bank details interfaces.

Comment: Hi Tom, I'm in the UK, i appreciate its a big ask! Didnt think it would be possible.

Comment: I believe most banks have an option to send you SMS alerts with this kind of information. No need to write code to do it unless this is a small part of a bigger app.

Comment: Hi MrKWatkins I have emailed them but no response as of yet, probably busy after Christmas.

Comment: Excellent idea Christian i all ready get the texts, i could hook somthing up with that. Hadnt thought of that, Thanks!

Comment: Out of interest, there are 'banking data aggregators' like `Yodlee` 
and `22seven` [(ref here)](http://www.iol.co.za/business/personal-finance/banking/use-financial-management-tool-at-your-own-risk-1.1227177#.UObAAG9QEjI) which are able to scrape or API their way into bank accounts.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? The answer might be 'no', but that doesn't make it a bad question.

Comment: Hi @JayMee, it was a while ago but still something i wish Banks did. But i can see the security implications. StackOverflow can be a harsh place :-P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe there is a startup that is doing this with browser plugins - can't remember who, but that might give you something to web-search on. (Edit: HSBC UK seem to offer integration [to these people](http://lessaccounting.com/bank-integration) via Yodlee.com - maybe worth investigating?).

The problem in the general case is that it is a breach of standard T&Cs for users to give out their credentials to a third party to do these queries, for obvious security reasons. However if users have a browser plugin to log on to their service and screen-scrape the data, there is no functional difference from the bank's perspective to the user actually logging on themselves.

I should think a template-based system that enabled screen design changes to be taken into account by the scraper quickly would be helpful here. It could download those changes from a central server, if the idea were to be commercialised.

Addendum: as a final thought, it may be worth considering that banks not offering a API system may paradoxically be less secure than not offering one at all. @StuartLC in the comments links to an article about a third party system that encourages customers to disclose their full security details - effectively their bank "root password". If banks offered an API system which permitted users to allow "read transactions only" with a separate set of credentials, that would be much safer.

Comment: Thanks Halfer, gives me somthing to go on, looks good!

Comment: @MrBeanzy - no problem. Added a final note.